# Codeigniter, get the total value of an Array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a total value of an array.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
echo $row->amount;
};
```

And that's echoing out plain numbers, such as

224
2344
24
2342
123 etc...

Now i'm just trying to echo out the total value.

Answer (score 2):

use `$this->db->select_sum();`

for example:

```
$this->db->select_sum('age');
$query = $this->db->get('members');
// Produces: SELECT SUM(age) as age FROM members
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just sum it to a variable (`$total`)  since you're iterating through all elements anyways.

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    echo $row->amount;
    $total += $row->amount;
};
echo $total;
```

Comment: I think it's better when the SQL calculates the sum.